# ServiceStack service URL in client and server

Tags: c#, rest, config, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack but am not sure how to approach what must be simple and common concepts. Perhaps this should be posted as two separate questions.

- How would I provide the server URL to the client? It's not inherently a ServiceStack problem but would like to know if there's something out of the box which I've missed. I'm thinking either through a config file for a client desktop application or perhaps a web service discovery mechanism, if such a thing exists.

*edit:* I am referring to the base / root URL of the server, where the clients are desktop applications (in some cases deployed in house). Most ServiceStack examples use a hard coded "localhost:82". So a mechanism to discover the real URL is needed..

- To generate a RESTful service I would like to provide links (href's) so that a client could potentially navigate without knowing too much about the service. Is there a simple way to do this? Is it a matter of extending my response DTOs and pushing these details? From a separation of concerns POV it doesn't feel like the best way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the built in ServiceStack metadata page can help you out on both accounts.  It should be available to you automatically at http//:[service_root]/metadata.  For example:

http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Northwind/metadata

You could provide this URL to a customer, and they should be able to interact with the service without issue.  It provides detailed information on all service operations, different ways to call them, and even sample request/responses in supported content-types.

You can provide operation descriptions to help clarify even further by decorating your request DTOs with the [Description] attribute.

```
[Description("This is a service description for thinger.")]
public class Thinger
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jeffmitchel however I'm thinking of the root server URL - also more about programmatically finding details by clients rather than reading the metadata page. Have updated my question.